# Check if a 24 hour timestamp falls within two time stamps

Tags: php, date

I am trying to write a function to check if a certain time (hh:mm) falls within two time stamps. The following method works fine except when the `$checktime` is after `23:00`. The window of start and endtimes are always roughly 30 min apart (doesn't span multiple days). How can I solve this problem?

```
<?php

    $startWindow = '2015-02-21 23:30:08';
    $endWindow = '2015-02-22 00:01:26';
    $checkTime = '23:44';
    $startTime = strtotime($startWindow);
    $endTime = strtotime($endWindow);

    $checkTime = strtotime($checkTime);
    if (($checkTime >= $startTime) && ($checkTime < $endTime)) {
        echo "In Range";
    }
    else {
        echo "Out of Range"; //gets printed
    }
```

Comment: military time ? similar question was asked 10 minutes ago, and was marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to get the date of the timestamp you want to check as well.

Add a variable `$checkDate` that is the date of the accompanying `$checkTime` in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Then change your code:

```
$checkTime = strtotime($checkDate . ' ' . $checkTime . ':00');
if (($checkTime >= $startTime) && ($checkTime < $endTime)) {
    echo "In Range";
}
else {
    echo "Out of Range"; //gets printed
}
```

Comment: Yep, was just about to say the same thing.

Comment: If I have `$startWindow = '2015-02-21 23:30:08'` and
`$endWindow = '2015-02-22 00:05:26';`
Both `$checkTime = '23:44';` and `$checkTime = '00:02'` should fall within the range. How can I pass a single $startDate and achieve this?

Comment: A time in this case means nothing without an accompanying date.  How do you know which day the `00:02` is?

Is it acceptable to assume that the date for the current timestamp is the current date?  If so, you set `$checkDate` as `date('Y-m-d');`

Answer (score 0):

You must set the date

```
<?php

$startWindow = '2015-02-21 23:30:08';
$endWindow = '2015-02-22 00:01:26';
$checkTime = '2015-02-21 23:44'; // or $checkTime = date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:44';
$startTime = strtotime($startWindow);
$endTime = strtotime($endWindow);

$checkTime = strtotime($checkTime);
if (($checkTime >= $startTime) && ($checkTime < $endTime)) {
    echo "In Range";
}
else {
    echo "Out of Range"; //gets printed
}
?>
```

Comment: @Nemo you got some advance?